# "expected type" while implementing delegate

Tags: ios, objective-c, appdelegate

I am writing just a piece of code, but taking an error that "expected type @line     - (void)backButtonTapped:(TopBarViewController *) topBarViewController;

What is wrong with this?

```
@protocol TopBarDelegate

- (void)backButtonTapped:(TopBarViewController *) topBarViewController;

@end


@interface TopBarViewController : UIViewController
{

}

@property (assign, nonatomic) id <TopBarDelegate> delegate;

-(void) backButtonPressed:(id)sender;

-(void) menuButtonPressed:(id)sender;

@end
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Add the following at the top. Since the protocol `TopBarDelegate` is defined above the class `TopBarViewController`, at the point you define the protocol, the compiler doesn't know there is a class called `TopBarViewController`. This line tells it there really is a class with that name defined somewhere.

```
@class TopBarViewController;
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that, when parsing that file, the compiler has no idea what `TopBarViewController` is.  It's just a random token that it doesn't know how to process.  That class is defined in a different file, so the compiler doesn't look at it while parsing this one.

You have two options:

- Import the header file that defines that class.
- Use `@class` to tell the compiler that it is a class defined elsewhere.

Generally speaking, the latter option is better, as it involves less work on the compiler's behalf and cannot lead to circular imports.

Comment: Option 1 is viable in this case since it is the same header.

Comment: Ah, I see, I misread the code a little.  The problem is essentially how I stated it, except rather than it being in an external file, it's above the declaration of the class itself.  The first option is not viable, the second option is what you should use.